# Texture Paint: Bump Map is stretched

Tags: texture-painting

The bump map on a specific object is stretched, while on other objects it appears normal. I painted a bump map on 2 different objects, both with exactly the same standard brush / texture / image settings.

I am quite certain that the problem has something to do with the object, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

[image]

Edit: I uploaded the .blend file here:

[image]

Comment: Just showing the result only tells us what you do not want. Please provide more information, for example how the texures look like, the UV maps that bring the textures onto the model, how the textrues are set up in the material...

Comment: Thanks @GordonBrinkmann for your response. As I don't know where to start looking for the problem, I don't know what information might be relevant. I just uploaded the file, so you can have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Improve UV Mapping

Your bump map appears to have been baked at a different scale than the base color, but the maps are is behaving as expected for how the textures were baked.

I recommend improving the UV mapping of the model, then try again to bake the textures. You can see how fragmented and unpredictable the UV map is in this screenshot. *UV > Unwrap > Smart UV Project* gives a decent result, but spending the time to place seams around the circumference might be best.

[image: fragmented UV map]